# Scaling and centering SVG with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Learning SVG / snap. With some help I can pull a region from a map and load it onto a modal per [the fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/0djhebes/)

I am now trying to keep the SVG within a `200px` by `200px` div, maintaining its aspect ratio, and to scale, so each region in the modal will fit in the above box but remain to scale against other regions.

```
   var m = Snap('#world-map');
   var d = Snap('#svg-region');
   var regionSVG = m.select('#' + region);
   var p = regionSVG.clone();
   d.append(p);
   var bb = regionSVG.getBBox();

   var vb = bb.x + ' ' + bb.y + ' ' + bb.width + ' ' + bb.height;
   d.attr({
     viewBox: vb
   })
```

I tried processing the data in the bbox to create a scale, but failed miserably.

```
function zoomBBox(bbox)
{
    var zbbox, ratio, diffx, diffy;
    var length = 200;

    if (bbox.width > bbox.height) {
        ratio = bbox.width / length;
        zbbox.width = length;
        zbbox.height = bbox.height * ratio;
    } else {
        ratio = bbox.height / length;
        zbbox.width = bbox.width * ratio;
        zbbox.height = length;
    }

    diffx = (zbbox.width - length) / 2;
    diffy = (zbbox.height - length) / 2;

    zbbox.x = bbox.x + diffx;
    zbbox.y = bbox.y + diffy;

    return zbbox;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to add the css `max-height: 100%;` to the svg?

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
.modal-body svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0djhebes/7/

Comment: Hi @caramba, thanks for this. But how do I scale each svg relative to others? Right now a small region fills the box just like a big region, losing its definition and stretching its content. On the project I have other markers also on the region which are getting scaled also. The solution I think is in the `viewBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the power of CSS :D

You need to define in the SVG #svg-region inside the modal via css HEIGHT & WIDTH that you want that they appear at their maximum.
For example 100px & 100px and they will be rendered inside that box

```
#svg-region{width:100px; height:100px;}
```

For aligning it, use a  as wrapper around #svg-region with the following css (I think that should work, didn't test it to align vertically and horizontally)

```
.wrapper{display:flex; jusfity-alignment:center; align-item:center;}
```